# Alternate Gothic No. 2 not embedding properly

Tags: actionscript-3, fonts, embedding

I'm writing a Pure AS3 app, embedding a font using the `Embed` metatag like so:

`[Embed(source="assets/fonts.swf", fontName="AlternateGothic No2")]

public static const ALTERNATE_GOTHIC_2:Class;`

This has always worked for me, but Alternate Gothic No. 2 gives me issues. In Flash, the font is labeled as `AlternateGothic` and the style is `No2`. I typically combine these with a space in between as the `fontName`, but it's not working.

The font is Postscript Type 1, so I can't embed the file and `fontFamily`, unless I spend $100+ on a font converter.

I also tried creating a font symbol, but that didn't work either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FontExplorerX has the font labeled as `AlternateGothic-No2`, so I tried that and it worked.

Comment: If you solve your own question you should still accept this as an answer so that the question is marked as solved.